# Neo4j: Properties in Node and Relationship objects

Tags: java, debugging, neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to debug through code in which I have a social network graph implemented using neo4j. While debugging I want to know app properties (with their values) contained in a Node or Relationship.

I attached screenshots for a Relationship object.

[image]
[image]

I thought it would be there in PropertIndexManager, but there in I got only property Keys and no corresponding values are present.

following is screenshot of propertyIndexManager:

[image]

Can anybody tell me where all relationship-properties (key-value pairs) are available in this object? similarly in Node object where I can find those node-properties (key-value pairs)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Neo4j server](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server.html) to view those poperties in a nice UI. Or just write a piece of code with outputs what you want.

Comment: Do you mean that it's not possible to watch those objects using "Expression" window in eclipse?

Comment: Don't think so, because it's basically a proxy you're trying to debug.

Comment: If you want an easy way to view the contents of Lucene index, I'd suggest you use [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/downloads/detail?name=lukeall-3.5.0.jar&can=2&q=).

Comment: you can call `x.getProperty(name)` in the inspect window.